# Correct way of updating, storing and deleting in many-to-many relationship in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I have this code and it's kinda working for storing and update but I don't know how to delete user's role by `detach` method. How can I delete a single role from multiple user's role? I am not sure about the codes along the `roles()->attach()` line which and I think you guys have a better solution to this.

**UsersController:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    if($request->isMethod('put'))
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($request->id);
        $user->name = $request->input('name');
        $user->email = $request->input('email');
        $role = Role::where('name',$request->input('role_id'))->first();
        $user->roles()->attach($role->id);
    }
    else
    {
        $user = new User;
        $user->name = $request->input('name');
        $user->email = $request->input('email');
        $user->password = Hash::make($request->input('password'));
        $user->remember_token = str_random(40);
        $user->id = User::count() + 1; //get the last user id? for pivot table
        $user->roles()->attach(2); //default role (2) : admin is (1)
    }

    if($user->save()){
        return response()->json($user);
    }
}
```

**User.php**

```
  public function roles(){
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
  }
```

**Role.php**

```
  public function users(){
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
  }
```

**Pivot table**

```
   Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method (not to say it is the right way) is to use the [sync](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships) method (**Syncing Associations**).

I create a dropdown list in the form.
I have a function sat in a model that does the following;

```
public function selectListValues($key, $value, $where=[])
{

    $list = [];

    if (is_array($value)) {

        array_unshift($value, $key);
        $result = $this->model->where($where)->get($value);

        foreach ($result->toArray() as $r) {
            $index = $r[$key];
            unset($r[$key]);
            $list[$index] = implode(' ', $r);
        }

    } else {

        try {
            $result = $this->model->where($where)->get()->pluck($value, $key);
            $list = $result->toArray();
        } catch(ModelNotFoundException $e){
            return null;
        }

    }

    return $list;

}
```

which I call in the function that generates the form;

```
$roles = $roleModel->selectListValues('id', 'name');
```

then in my store method of the controller;

```
$roles = $request->get('roles');

$collection = new Collection();

foreach ($roles as $role) {
    try {
        $collection->add(Role::where('id', '=', $role)->firstOrFail());
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        dd($e);
    }
}

if (empty($collection)) {
    throw new \Exception('No roles found for '.$user->email);
}

$user->roles()->sync($collection);
```

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough answer, I also got it working by changing the attach to sync, which you've suggested.